# Reusable uncontrolled input with react-hook-form. Type error for `register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>` prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I want to have a reusable uncontrolled Input component using `react-hook-form`, but I can't seem to get the types right.

Something like this:

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-feather-9jleoc?file=/src/App.tsx) with the example.

**Obs.:** The code seems to be running just fine. I think it's just a matter of adjusting the types.

```
// REUSABLE UNCONTROLLED INPUT

interface NoteInputValue extends FieldValues {
  note: string;
}

type NoteInputProps = {
  register: UseFormRegister<NoteInputValue>;
};

const NoteInput: React.FC<NoteInputProps> = (props) => {
  const { register } = props;
  return <input {...register("note")} />;
};
```

This is the form component:

```
// SOME FORM COMPONENT THAT NEEDS
// TO USE THE INPUT

interface FormValues extends FieldValues {
  note: string;
  someOtherField: boolean;
}

type MyFormProps = {};

const MyForm: React.FC<MyFormProps> = (props) => {
  const { register } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      note: "",
      someOtherField: true
    }
  });
  return (
    <>
      <NoteInput register={register} />
    </>
  );
};
```

This is the TypeScript error I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to have it documented here, I found two approaches that could work, but aren't ideal, imo.
My ultimate goal is to just pass the `register` function and it should be able to register the `name` of the input that it already has knowledge of, without receiving the `name` as props.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-brook-2yknnc

```
// REUSABLE UNCONTROLLED INPUT

interface InputValue {
  note: string;
}

interface NoteInputProps<FormValues> {
  register: UseFormRegister<FormValues>;
}

const NoteInput = <FormValues extends InputValue>(
  props: NoteInputProps<FormValues>
) => {
  const { register } = props;

  // Note:
  // Couldn't get rid of the `name` type assertion as Path<FormValues>.
  // Even though `FormValues extends InputValue` (so it must
  // have the `note` field). We get an error if we try to call
  // register('note') without the type assertion

  const name = "note" as Path<FormValues>;

  return <input {...register(name)} />;
};
```

Or, passing the `name` explicitly (which was what I was trying to avoid):

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-northcutt-9hb5t2?file=/src/App.tsx

```
// REUSABLE UNCONTROLLED INPUT

interface InputValue {
  note: string;
}

interface NoteInputProps<FormValues> {
  name: FieldPath<FormValues>;
  register: UseFormRegister<FormValues>;
}

const NoteInput = <FormValues extends InputValue>(
  props: NoteInputProps<FormValues>
) => {
  const { name, register } = props;
  return <input {...register(name)} />;
};
```